# Android decode image into bitmap from byte array of image

Tags: android, json, image, bitmap

I have an problem. I don't get any idea, how to decode image into bitmap from below json response.

```
response: [{"namae":"example",
    photo:[125,122,10,22,34,5,5,56,5,0,0,..........................,23]}]
```

I don't know how to get bitmap image from value of photo parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `decodeByteArray()` from `BitmapFactory` class

Answer (score 0):

Get the bytes from the json, lets call it

```
bytes photoBytes=array.getJSONArray(0);
```

Do this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoBytes,0,photoBytes.length,options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, <preferredWidth>, <preferredHeight>);
        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmp1=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoBytes,0,photoBytes.length,options);

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;}
```

check [google site](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for more info